# Forward ports over hostapd?

Tags: iptables, nat, dnsmasq, wifi-hotspot, hostapd

I'm running this [project for creating access points](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) which is built on top of `hostapd`.

Running this works as expected, my ethernet connection is available as wifi:

```
sudo create_ap wlan0 eth0 wifiname
```

I was hoping that port 80 on my host machine would automatically be exposed to the client but it isn't.

How can I create a `hostapd` hotspot that exposes port 80? I'm thinking I might need to use `iptables` or `dnsmasq` but I'm not sure.

*I'm using the project linked as a starting point but my main goal is to broadcast a port over a wifi-hot spot.*

---

**Update:** I found that by default the host is available at IP `192.168.12.1`. I'm now looking for a way to forward all *(or at minimum localhost)* traffic on the hotspot to this IP.

But I still need to be able to resolve other domains on the host itself.

Comment: You must bind the port to appropriate device (presumably `wlan0`). If you need it open on `eth0` too - `iptables` / `nftables` is your answer.

Comment: I just tried your script and it worked fine. I created hotspot on my laptop and connected my phone to it. Started a server on `443`. In phone, opening `https://192.168.12.1` worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the behavior I wanted using `dnsmasq`. Originally I was confused because I was adding the following to the default `dnsmasq.conf` location:

```
address=/#/192.168.12.1
```

It should forward all traffic to the IP `192.168.12.1` but I found it wasn't working.

Later on while running `top` with the program running I found that `create_ap` had called `dnsmasq` but with a custom `dnsmasq.conf` in a `/tmp/` folder.

Reading through the source I found [this snippet](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap/blob/master/create_ap#L1686):

```
    MTU=$(get_mtu $INTERNET_IFACE)
    [[ -n "$MTU" ]] && echo "dhcp-option-force=option:mtu,${MTU}" >> $CONFDIR/dnsmasq.conf
    [[ $ETC_HOSTS -eq 0 ]] && echo no-hosts >> $CONFDIR/dnsmasq.conf
    [[ -n "$ADDN_HOSTS" ]] && echo "addn-hosts=${ADDN_HOSTS}" >> $CONFDIR/dnsmasq.conf
    if [[ "$SHARE_METHOD" == "none" && "$REDIRECT_TO_LOCALHOST" == "1" ]]; then
        cat << EOF >> $CONFDIR/dnsmasq.conf
address=/#/$GATEWAY
```

Inside that statement I added the following line to add my configuration to the temporary dnsmasq file:

```
echo "address=/#/${GATEWAY}" >> $CONFDIR/dnsmasq.conf
```

After adding that any `http` address on the AP was forwarding to `192.168.12.1` the browser automatically assumes port 80 when one isn't provided so that became a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that via hostapd because port 80 is at Layer4 of ISO/OSI stack, APs work at Layer2. So you need to identify your IP connected via WIFI and work with IPTABLES for that IP